# Help regarding calculating z statistic and p value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, z-test, arithmetic

I am trying to solve a problem but couldn't see any way around it.

So far, here is the progress

$\mu_{pop} = 10 $

$\sigma_{pop} = \sqrt12$

$\mu_{sample} = 12$

$z = (\mu_{sample} - \mu_{pop})/(\sigma_{pop}/\sqrt15) = 0.14 $

What am I doing wrong in it?

[image]

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Comment: You are using $\sigma_{pop} = \sqrt{10}$, but the population variance is 12 and $\sqrt{10}$ is not the square root of 12.

Comment: The answer should be sqrt(5).

Comment: @jbowman, I am using $\sqrt12$ in calculation. Description corrected.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, yes apparently. Did you solve this?

Comment: You are doing something wrong, because I get the right answer too.  My guess is that you aren't doing the divisions correctly.

Comment: Aw, my bad. I got it finally :)

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to get to the z-stat
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test

Z-Stat:

z = (M - u) / SE

- M is the mean of the sample = 12
- u is the mean of the population = 10
- SE (Standard Error) = Standard Deviation / SQRT(sample size n)

SE = Sd / SQRT(n)

- n = 15
- Sd = SQRT(Standard Deviation) = SQRT(15)
- SE = SQRT(12)/SQRT(15) = 0.894427191

z = (M - u) / SE

z = (12 - 10) / 0.894427191 = 2.2360679775 = **2.24**